# Unable to generate Quote template after sandbox refresh

Tags: quote, cpq, quote-template

We just refreshed our sandbox and when I try to generate or Preview quote document, it is showing as blank.

Are there any settings that need to be done after sandbox refresh for quote templates to work?

Below is the screenshot, when I am trying to preview Quote document:

[image]

Tried below things but didn't resolve.

1. Our sandbox has my domain enabled and I even added new url in the
   remote site settings.
2. Setup -> Installed Packages -> Salesforce CPQ -> Configure -> "Additional Settings" tab and clicked on "Execute Scripts" button.

Answer (score 1):

Check for URL references in your template content. For example, if you have images in HTML Content, they may be referencing your production URL.